# Laravel collection filter to return data based on condition

Tags: php, laravel

I wonder if it's possible to filter a laravel collection based on a specific attribute value.

```js
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "perm_id": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "perm_id": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "perm_id": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "perm_id": 1  
  }
]
```

This is how the structure of my collection looks like. I have multiple objects with the same `perm_id`. I need to return the object with the highest `id` for each `perm_id`. So the final return value should be like:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "perm_id": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "perm_id": 1  
  }
]
```

Comment: can't you just groupBy the entries by perm_id and take only the entries with the highest id?

Comment: Related: [How to get the max value for elements having the same id under Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48748319/2943403), [Get maximum values in column with diferents foreign ids in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61138334/2943403), [Laravel Collection group by with max value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34363281/2943403)

Comment: ... [Get the DISTINCT id of users and find the MAX of their column then UPDATE, LARAVEL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53329885/2943403), [Eloquent get only latest per value on column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63592704/2943403), [Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created_at](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47959102/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this->

```
$arr = [
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "perm_id" => 1,
    ],
    [
        "id" => 3,
        "perm_id" => 1,
    ],
    [
        "id" => 10,
        "perm_id" => 2,
    ],
    [
        "id" => 9,
        "perm_id" => 1
    ]
];

$filtered = collect($arr)   // convert array to Collection
    ->sortByDesc('id')      // sort by id, in descending order
    ->unique('perm_id')     // get perm_id's 1st occurrence value as it is sorted, it will get highest value
    ->values()              // reset array keys
    ->toArray()             // convert back to array
;
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 10,
        "perm_id": 2,
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "perm_id": 1  
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group all items by `perm_id` and then map them to get the highest `id`.

```
$arr = [
    (object) [
        "id" => 2,
        "perm_id" => 1,
    ],
    (object) [
        "id" => 3,
        "perm_id" => 1,
    ],
    (object) [
        "id" => 10,
        "perm_id" => 2,
    ],
    (object) [
        "id" => 9,
        "perm_id" => 1  
    ]
];

$filtered = collect($arr)->sortByDesc('id')->groupBy('perm_id')->map(fn($item) => $item[0]);

dd($filtered);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is find in the documentation of Laravel:
Using a map function you can filter by an atribute value.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections

```
$collection = collect(['taylor', 'abigail', null])->map(function ($name) {
return strtoupper($name);
})->reject(function ($name) {
    return empty($name);
});
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question he is asking. And map function **does not** filter by an atribute value.